# How to Execute something after commit?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, yii2

Is there any way to run some code after the transaction commits in Yii2?

I have one form, after submit, it will save data in 3 4 related tables, and one is the parent table.

Before commit, all records in relative tables will be inserted.

And after commit, I want to generate one code based on all data which will be saved in 3, 4 tables.

But the problem happens when, after commit, I am trying to update generated code, in the saved record, but; I am not getting record until then, because it is not saved or commit operation is under process.

I want all this flow sync.

I haven't found any generic way of doing it in Yii2. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Add your code, as far i understood, you have models loaded with data and you can update them before transaction commit and  afterwards you need to save models again to update db.

Comment: Yes correct. ...